# Can't change one specific registry value from Java process

Tags: java, windows, registry

While I can create/change almost any key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER, it doesn't seem possible to invoke the following command via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyOverride" /d "<local>" /f
```

The result of this command is always 0 (success).

Adding different keys via Java works flawlessly. However this one specific key is not visible in regedit afterwards.

Has my Java process different privileges than cmd? Both run with the same user (verified by invoking `whoami`).

---

Edit: The solution proposed by David in [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) doesn't work either.

---

Edit 2: Turns out, it did actually work but was immediately revoked by a following invocation of a `net use` command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)